# Using Google Cloud Storage as origin for Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution and want to use Google Cloud Storage as its one of the origin. How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

As per [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html) :

> When you use a custom origin, you specify the DNS name of the server,
>   along with the HTTP and HTTPS ports and the protocol that you want
>   CloudFront to use when fetching objects from your origin.

So an http or https endpoint should be good to add as custom origin.

.

Comment: If the GCS bucket is not publicly-accessible, you'd also need to also implement request authentication code to sign those requests, in a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger, so that GCS would serve them.  But this answer is fundamentally correct.